# Why is there no serialize to JSON in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization

Hi a couple of days ago I had to post a js object to the server via ajax and I discovered there was no way to convert an object to JSON using jQuery.

So it's really a two part question: 
1. Why is a toJSON() method not included in jQuery and 2. what is the best way to post a js object to the server?

Cheers,

Joe

Comment: It's impossible to objectively answer this question; questions of this type are too open ended and usually lead to confrontation and argument.

Comment: As for part 1, that's impossible to answer conclusively, unless one of the jQuery authors/devs happens to read the question and is able to answer. And part 2 *seems* subjective/argumentative.

Comment: Question 2 would be fine for a Community Wiki. Question 1 could only be answered by the jQuery developers.

Answer (score 1):

normally you dont pass JSON but you serialize your data, hence the `.serialize()` it's normally the server that sends json... not the client.

the best way is to serialize the object.

> http://api.jquery.com/serialize/